# Effect of IsBackground on .Net Threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I know that when the main method is running and the only other threads that are running are background threads then the application exits. Other than delaying program termination or not, does a backgrounded thread do anything differently or respond differently than a non-backgrounded thread?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they are identical to normal threads except they don't prevent a process from terminating.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)

> Background threads are identical to
>   foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a
>   process from terminating.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the explanation given in this book on Threading
http://www.albahari.com/threading/